# How to fix laggy mouse and keyboard on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS 64bit?

Tags: 10.04, keyboard, mouse

I've just installed Ubuntu 10.04 LTS 64bit on my i5-2400 system, and I'm experiencing very laggy keyboard and mouse input.

I have to type really slowly or I some keys will not get registered. Also, the mouse cursor moves around very slowly at a very low frame rate.

I've checked my keyboard and mouse settings and they seem to be fine. System monitor doesn't show any processes taking up significant CPU utilization. What else could be wrong?

---

Anyway, I'm using 10.04 LTS since I'm building the Android source code and that's the official supported version. I tried using 12.04LTS but it didn't work.

And my keyboard/mouse are both USB, not PS/2.

I suspect it's a driver issue, probably something to do with my USB drivers, but not sure where to get updated drivers backported for 10.04?

Answer (score 0):

I found this problem solved on my computer when I upgraded to 12.04LTS, I would recommend giving this a try. Is there any specific reason that you are still using 10.04LTS on such a powerful system?

Answer (score 0):

I had a laggy keyboard input when I used a desktop's keyboard(pinned one) with a converter to work with my laptop's usb port.

If that's the case with you, I think you should switch to an usb keyboard.